# Images inside a list displaying on one row

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists, inline

On this site [mmandjlaw.com](http://mmandjlaw.com) I have added new lawyers to our practice, but now there is white space and I cannot figure out why?

What I tried and did not work:

- Using `display: inline-block;`
- Changing to `width: 24%;`

I do not see any margins. Pictures are all the same size.

I have decent knowledge HTML and CSS, but how would I troubleshoot issues like this?

Comment: Please show your code snippet, by that we can help you to resolved problem. Thanks.

Comment: Is your question still valid? At least in Chrome 65 no white space appears between the photos. If so, could you add a screenshot showing what isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

use inline-block but comment the space between elements like so

`<li>
    content
  </li><!--
--><li>
    content2
  </li>`